# choices with model in the form field in the django test

Tags: django, django-forms, django-testing

I have this form:

```
class Dashboard(forms.Form):
        year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Year.objects.all().values_list('pk', 'year'))
```

and my test is not running because of the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: common_year
```

Comment: like in the error django is providing to you it seams that Django cannot see that table in the database, so first things first, did you make the proper migrations?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Django is trying to fetch the queryset when the `forms.py` is loaded, but the table has not been created yet.

You can fix the error by using a callable for `choices`. This means that the queryset is not evaluated until the form is instantiated.

```
def year_choices():
    return Year.objects.all().values_list('pk', 'year')

class Dashboard(forms.Form):
    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=year_choices)
```

Another option is to use a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) instead.

```
class Dashboard(forms.Form):
    year = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Year.objects.all())
```

Comment: I used: class Dashboard(forms.Form):
    year = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Year.objects.all())